# how to output AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment variables in a page

Tags: environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, razor-pages

In my test c# .net core razor pages site, I just want to create an environment variable called "myVarTest" and just show its value on my index page (to confirm it works, before i start using it)

However, my local version, shows my enviornment var has been populated, but when i upload to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, it shows nothing

```
NameValueCollection appConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
EnvVar = $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("myVarTest")} - aspcore: {Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}";
```

so, this shows myVarTest value and the value for ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT), here is my launchsettings

```
"profiles": {
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
    "myVarTest": "here we are1"
  }
},
"NameOfSite": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
    "myVarTest": "here we are2"
  },
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
},
```

And, here is where i set them up in AWS...

[image]

Does anyone knows what i am missing? or have i got this totally wrong?

Comment: even looping through here doesnt so the variable i setup on AWS :(
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed... very annoying... if you publish to aws elastic beanstalk and have it using Windows server 2016, it doesnt work... no idea why, but you cant access your environment variables

if, however, you deploy to elastic beanstalk with Amazon Linux 2, then all you need to do, is add your property in the AWS window i mention above, then you can display by just doing:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("hmmTest1")
```

all working now